# Difference between "with" and "of"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> S is the set of 2 elements.
>
> S is the set with 2 elements.

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: I think that "of" implies possession (if A possesses B then saying B of A (or B belongs to) makes sense), "with" implies attachment (A with B doesn't necessarily mean B belongs to A). But if A possesses B, it's okay to say A with B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sentences are a little confusing, because they seem to be very technical.  A set containing elements is usually only used when describing things mathematically - a set of prime numbers, for instance.  Technical fields will often have specific grammar expectations that may be unique, so it is important to provide context.

In terms of English language usage, "of" means the things that make up the set, while "with" means things that are contained within the set.  "Of" is the entire set, while "with" may be part of the set.

For instance, let's say that I have a basket containing puppies.

If I describe it as "a basket *of* puppies", you could infer that the only thing in the basket is puppies. The basket might contain other objects like a blanket or a chew toy, but as far as the speaker is concerned the only significant objects in the basket are the puppies.

If I describe it as "a basket *with* puppies", there is a possibility that the basket contains other important things that are being overlooked.  For instance, there could also be a sleeping cat.

If I hand my friend a basket *with* puppies (and also a cat), and she has an allergic reaction to the cat, I can claim to have been truthful.  If I tell her it is a basket *of* puppies and don't mention the cat, she can claim I misled her.

Comment: The sentences probably wouldn't sound quite as technical if the indefinite article was used: *S is **a** set of 2 elements; T is a set with 2 elements.*

Comment: I disagree, *A basket with puppies* does not suggest that the puppies are in the basket, it only indicates that the puppies are supplemental to the basket.